# APACHE POI - Not able to give background colour to a cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am generating excel file using java poi and trying to add a background color for the column heading in the excel.

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.BIG_SPOTS);
        row.setRowStyle(style);

        for(RiskVo h : selectedExcel){
            row.createCell(h.getIndex()).setCellValue(h.getRisk_disc_en());
        }
```

But the color only displayed in the low to empty columns.

[image]
I want the background color for the first row. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create the cell and then set the style inside the loop. It's work for me.

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
  style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
  style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

for(RiskVo h : selectedExcel){
    row.createCell(h.getIndex()).setCellValue(h.getRisk_disc_en());
    row.getCell(h.getIndex()).setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `h.getIndex()` starts from the beginning of worksheet. So after setting style for a row, you create new cells at the beginning of row and move existing cells to the right. Your solutions are:

1. Create headers cells and then set style

Example

```
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

for(RiskVo h : selectedExcel){
    row.createCell(h.getIndex()).setCellValue(h.getRisk_disc_en());
}

CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.BIG_SPOTS);
row.setRowStyle(style);
```

2. After setting style, don't create new cells, but get cells from row instead and insert value.

Comment: for(RiskVo h : selectedExcel){
            row.createCell(h.getIndex()).setCellValue(h.getRisk_disc_en());
            row.getCell(h.getIndex()).setCellStyle(style);
        }                                                                                                                                     like this.

Comment: @Naveen But I think your solution should work as well

Answer (score 0):

I have a really handy utility class I created to very easily color the background of a cell, change text color, and a lot of other stuff you might need to create really awesome spreadsheets from code. They are static methods and they instantly return `CellStyle`.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

/*
    Utility Class for Spreadsheet Cell Styling
 */

public class CellStyles {

public static CellStyle getTableHeaderStyle(Workbook workbook){
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    font.setFontName("Times New Roman");
    style.setWrapText(true);
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    style.setLocked(true);

    return style;
}

public static CellStyle getShadedCellStyle(Workbook workbook, HSSFColor foreground, HSSFColor background ){
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    font.setFontName("Times New Roman");
    style.setFont(font);

    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(foreground.getIndex());
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(background.getIndex());
    style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    style.setLocked(true);

    return style;
}

public static CellStyle getColoredTextCellStyle(Workbook workbook, HSSFColor color){
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    font.setFontName("Times New Roman");
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setFillBackgroundColor(color.getIndex());
    style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    font.setColor(color.getIndex());

    return style;
}
```

}

An example would be:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
CellStyle style = CellStyles.getShadedCellStyle(workbook, new HSSFColor.BRIGHT_GREEN(), new HSSFColor.BLACK()));
...
someCell.setCellStyle(style);
```